# django: sending mails in two different ways

Tags: django, sendmail

I'll try to explain my problem differently

I tried sending mails in two different ways
the first with the development server
I wrote in the settings file:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'patrice.kerviel@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

For the models file:

```
send_mail (u "demande_Expertise 'message' '
 [instance.categorie.expert.utilisateur.email] fail_silently = False)
```

Sending mail works perfectly ..

But when the program is installed on the production server (apache), sending mails does not work

I wrote in the settings file:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mailhost.onera'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'patrice.kerviel@onera.fr'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and the following error is returned:

STARTTLS extension not supported by server

if I change by:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

the following error is returned:

AUTH extension not supported by server

I would like to know why it works with the development server and not when the program is installed on a network?

Comment: Er, because you're using a different mail server?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. You can edit your original question and add details. If sending mail works with another mail server, then it sounds like you'd be better asking `onera.fr` for help instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: if I had found help in my work, I will not ask the problem here